# POST sent via AJAX comes out empty

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, codeigniter, post

So I have the following jQuery block;

```
var file = "something.html";
$.post("/load", {which: file}, function(data){
  // do stuff
});
```

Which is supposed to call a backend that loads a file. The `load` controller (I'm on CodeIgniter 2.1.3) looks like so;

```
class Load extends MY_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $file = $this->input->post("which");
        $content = get_file_contents($file);
        echo $content;
    }
}
```

However, for some reason, the `$file` variable remains empty.

Now, I've tested that the `load` controller **does actually work**, by changing the `$this->input->post()` into a `$this->input->get()` and visiting the page from the browser (e.g. `/load?which=something.html`); the correct file is loaded and echoed.

I've debugged the code by using **the plain `$_POST`** variable instead of the CodeIgniter handler. `$_POST["which"]` comes up as an undefined index error.

As per suggestions from other threads, **I've also tried `var_dump()` on `$_POST` and `file_get_contents('php://input')`**, and they both come up as empty. For all intents and purposes the backend is just not receiving any POST data.

From the Network section of my Inspector, I can see that **the AJAX call is indeed sent**, and the "Form Data" section contains `which: something.html` as it should. The request is returned with a 404 Not Found status code. However, I do know that the proper controller is indeed contacted as adding `echo "test"; exit;` into the controller before it all does indeed return "test" for the AJAX request.

As far as I've found solution candidates online, my php.ini should be proper; I've made sure that `variables_order` contains `P` and `post_max_size` is a reasonable size. And as some answerers suggested that it might be an .htaccess redirect thing, I did try adding a trailing slash to the URL that the JS requests, but all to no avail.

Here's my .htaccess for reference;

```
# Customized error messages.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

This same code has worked in the past, but now I'm on a new computer with a fresh install of Apache (2.2.22) and PHP (5.3.13), which leads me to believe that this is most likely some sort of config issue with either Apache or PHP. I don't know if that makes this thread more suitable for Server Fault than Stack Overflow, but as I am a programmer and not a system admin, I thought to see if anyone here has any thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried wrapping `which` around quotes - `{"which": file}`?

Comment: what does it shows when you try yoursite/load ?

Comment: are u missing site_url() there.... `$.post(<?php echo site_url('load') ?>...`....

Comment: @asprin that change will be consumed by the javascript interpreter and will not be visible inside `$.post`

Comment: What was the PHP version where it worked?

Comment: @JanDvorak Didn't knew that. I always quote the `keys` of the data being passed :)

Comment: I don't see the Options line. Try adding this `Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews` on top of the rewrite rule-set.

Comment: @asprin it's required in JSON, but not by Javascript

Comment: @faa That only seems to produce a 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Where did you do the var_dump($_POST)? Try doing that in index.php - very first line, then exit. Helps narrow down where the breakdown in communications is

Comment: @JanDvorak Just dug up my old laptop; the previous localhost was running Apache 2.2.21 and PHP 5.3.10. Because of the version change I didn't move over the php.ini and Apache conf files directly, but tried to replicate every config edit from the previous setup on the fresh files.

Comment: @Robbie I did it on the very first line of the `index` function in the `load` controller.

Comment: @EmphramStavanger try `diff`ing the two `.ini` files

Comment: Check MAX_POST_SIZE is not 0 (or invalid - i.e. check it's 8M and not 8MB). That will give you what you experience.

Comment: @JanDvorak Yup, that was it. I made sure I had all the same Apache modules and PHP extensions on that I had on the old machine and now it works again. Duh. Thanks everybody! :)

Comment: @EmphramStavanger you should compile your findings and solution into a self-answer and post it for the benefits of others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Jan Dvorak's sharp suggestion, I compared the configuration of the current environment with that of the one where the code last worked, and I made sure the lists of enabled Apache modules and PHP extensions were identical.

During this process I turned on the following Apache modules in addition to the ones I already had on;

- auth_digest_module
- dav_lock_module
- headers_module
- info_module
- proxy_module
- proxy_ajp_module
- ssl_module
- status_module

I also turned on the following PHP extensions that were not on previously;

- php_bz2
- php_curl
- php_exif
- php_gettext
- php_imap
- php_openssl
- php_pdo_odbc
- php_pdo_sqlite
- php_soap
- php_sockets
- php_sqlite
- php_sqlite3
- php_xmlrpc

A smarter man than me can tell me which module or extension or combination thereof was the exact solution for this issue.

However, for me, enabling these modules and extensions allowed me to make sure my environment was similar to my previous one, and in this case, solved the issue for me with no changes required to the code or `.htaccess`.